# XSLT generates unwanted namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like this:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd           http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd           http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd          http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd">
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="pot_kodtar_service" update-strategy="reload"/>
...
<bean class="xxxxx.fuse.util.CommonAuthInterceptor" id="authorizationInterceptor">
    <property name="methodRolesMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="xxxElemE1" value="xxxElemE1Role"/>
            <entry key="xxxTipusE1" value="xxxTipusE1Role"/>
            <entry key="xxxLekerdezE1" value="xxxLekerdezE1Role"/>
            <entry key="xxxValtozasE1" value="xxxValtozasE1Role"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="globalRoles" value="xxxUsers"/>
</bean>
```

And I want to append a new element after the last entry. If I found the last element without namespace like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="*:map/*:entry[last()]">     
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>       
        <entry key="{$service-name}" value="{$service-name}Role"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I get extra namesapces in the output document like this:

```
               <entry key="xxxValtozasE1" value="xxxValtozasE1Role"/> <!-- that is last existing element-->
        <entry xmlns=""
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               key="xxxElemKeresE1"
               value="xxxElemKeresE1Role"/> <!-- that is newly added element with unwanted namespaces-->
```

The inserted entry contains extra xmlns:="" and xmlns:xsd="..." definitions. How can I eliminate these extra namespace definitions?

thx
Zamek

Comment: Actually, the declaration xmlns="" means that the element has *fewer* namespaces than it would have without this declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"` and `exclude-result-prefixes="xsd"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` root element of your stylesheet. The first suggestion should put result elements in the output namespace and the second should avoid the output of the `xmlns:xsd` which I suppose you have declared in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule with XSLT and namespaces is: make sure you generate your elements with the right expanded name, and the namespace declarations will take care of themselves.

You want to generate an element with expanded name ("http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0", "entry"), but you have actually generated an element with expanded name ("", "entry").

Change the literal result element to

```
<entry key="{$service-name}" value="{$service-name}Role" xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"/>
```

so the element now has the right expanded name, and the unwanted namespace undeclaration will disappear.

Comment: Sorry I don't want to get extra ns. The ns will be eliminated when I use  exclude-result-prefixes="xsd" in the xslt root.

Answer (score 0):

The  exclude-result-prefixes="xsd" in the root of xslt is seems to be good for one of the element, which is deep inside the xml like this: /bean/property/map/entry. Unfortunately I have an other element under root named route:

```
        <route id="xxxModositE1_Route" streamCache="true">
        <from id="xxxModositE1_from1" uri="cxf:bean:xxxModositE1_LocalEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
        <convertBodyTo
            id="xxxModositE1_convertBodyTo1" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <wireTap id="xxxModositE1_wireTap1" uri="direct-vm:logRequest"/>
        <to id="xxxModositE1_to2" uri="cxf:bean:xxxModositE1_RemoteEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
        <convertBodyTo
            id="xxxModositE1_convertBodyTo3" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <wireTap id="xxxModositE1_wireTap3" uri="direct-vm:logResponse"/>
    </route>
```

I try to match it with:

```
 <xsl:template match="*:route[last()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>       
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select='$service-name'/></xsl:comment>
    <route id="{$service-name}_xslt_Route" streamCache="true" xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
        <from id="{$service-name}_from1" uri="cxf:bean:{$service-name}_LocalEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
        <convertBodyTo id="{$service-name}_convertBodyTo1" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <wireTap id="{$service-name}_wireTap1" uri="direct-vm:logRequest"/>
        <to id="{$service-name}_to2" uri="cxf:bean:{$service-name}_RemoteEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
        <convertBodyTo id="{$service-name}_convertBodyTo3" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <wireTap id="{$service-name}_wireTap3" uri="direct-vm:logResponse"/>
    </route>
    <!--  -->
</xsl:template>
```

and the result will be:

```
 <route xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
         id="TorzsHorizontKomplexKodtarElemKeresE1_xslt_Route"
         streamCache="true">
...
```

Of course I don't want extra xmlns in this element. Is the position relevant? Here is the root of my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xsd">
```

thx
Zamek

Comment: If you want to provide further details you are supposed to edit your question with that details, not to use the answer function. So consider to move those details to the question. But you will need to show us in more detail which namespaces are involved and which namespaces you want for which new elements.